# Adding GTSAM to the project

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to add GTSAM to the project and it doesnt find the boost.
I installed GTSAM and boost and tried to add GTSAM following the example from GTSAM repo.
My CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(project1 CXX)
set(GTSAM_DIR "C:/gtsam/gtsam/build")
find_package(GTSAM)
if(GTSAM_FOUND)  
  message(STATUS "Found GTSAM ${GTSAM_VERSION}")
else()
  message(STATUS "GTSAM Not Found")
endif()

include_directories(${GTSAM_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(project1
  main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(project1 PRIVATE gtsam)
```

After trying to configure it with cmake I get this error:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/gtsam/gtsam/build/GTSAMConfig.cmake

  but it set GTSAM_FOUND to FALSE so package "GTSAM" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  GTSAM could not be found because dependency Boost could not be found.
```

During GTSAM installation I didnt have a problem with Boost so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: How did you build and install `GTSAM`? If you give it a hint about Boost location, then you need to give the same hint in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you built GTSAM yourself.
Try to extend your CMakeLists.txt like this:

First make sure you have boost installed `sudp apt install libboost-dev`

```
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )
include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GTSAM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(project1
  main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(factor_graph_slam
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${GTSAM_LIBRARIES}
)
```

You might have to do the same thing with Eigen and TBB, depending on how you built GTSAM (`find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` and `find_package(TBB REQUIRED)` plus adding the to the includes and linked libraries)